# Reading csv files into table in GAMS

Tags: csv, gams-math

I am having trouble reading CSV files into table. Suppose I have csv file looking like:

```
;c1;c1;c3;c4
r1;(some numeric values separated by ";")
r2;(some numeric values separated by ";")
```

I have tried to rewrite the `csv` into a `.inc` file and replacing `;`with spaces. And then do something like this:

```
set col /c1 * c4/
set row /r1 * r2/


table(row, col)
   $include("myfile.inc")
;
```

But this doesn't work because my collins are not aligned and I can't do it manually because I have more than 500 columns.

My problem can be solved by

1. finding a way to define `table` entries without the text being aligned
2. find way to read csv directly into GAMS

What you suggest I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that could help you:

- Setting $onDelim (https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_DollarControlOptions.html#DOLLARonoffdelim)
- Using csv2gdx (https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/T_CSV2GDX.html)

Comment: I have looked at the last one but couldn't make it work. I am gonna try your first suggestion